# Check if String Contains Number from List, Remove that Number from String

Tags: c#, regex

I want to check if a string contains a word or number from a list and remove it from the string.

I want to do this for multiple matches found.

---

The sentence reads

> This is a 01 02 03 (01) (02) (03) no01 no02 no03 test

---

I need the `Regex.Replace` to remove only the full `01`, `02`, `03`, not the ones inside other words.

> This is a (01) (02) (03) no01 no02 no03 test

---

But it only removes the occurrences of 03, the last item in the match list, in all places.

> This is a 01 02  (01) (02) () no01 no02 no test

---

http://rextester.com/BCEXTJ37204

**C#**

```
List<string> filters = new List<string>();
List<string> matches = new List<string>();

string sentence = "This is a 01 02 03 (01) (02) (03) no01 no02 no03 test";
string newSentence = string.Empty;

// Create Filters List
for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
{
    filters.Add(string.Format("{0:00}", i)); // 01-100
}

// Find Matches
for (int i = 0; i < filters.Count; i++)
{
    // Add to Matches List
    if (sentence.Contains(filters[i]))
    {
        matches.Add(filters[i]); // will be 01, 02, 03
    }
}

// Filter Sentence
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    newSentence = Regex.Replace(sentence, matches[i], "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}

// Display New Sentence
Console.WriteLine(newSentence);
```

I tried changing `string.Format()` to `@"\b{0:00}\b"` to match whole words but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide some edge case examples to be clear about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @JoePhillips I just want to remove matching whole words/numbers that are in the filters list. But preserve them if they are contained within another word. That way the filter doesn't damage the wrong words by removing parts.

Comment: Should it remove 999999? How about 1? how about -99? There are a lot of edge cases.  A simple regex replace would probably work (without a loop), so I'm trying to understand why you're looping at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are invoking your regex matcher repeatedly on the original string. That's why only the last change "sticks", while the rest get discarded:

```
newSentence = Regex.Replace(sentence, matches[i], "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

If you change this to call `Replace` on `newSentence`, it is going to work correctly:

```
newSentence = sentence;
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++) {
    newSentence = Regex.Replace(newSentence, matches[i], "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

However, this is suboptimal: you would be better off concatenating all replacements into a single regex, like this:

```
newSentence = Regex.Replace(
    sentence
,   @"(?<=\s|^)(" + string.Join("|", matches) + @")(?=\s|$)"
,   ""
,   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
```

You can also remove pre-checks of `filters` that constructs `matches`, because regex engine would take care of it pretty efficiently.

[Demo.](http://rextester.com/MFOJH31286)

Comment: It removes the matches, but I only want it to remove `01 02 03`, but not `(01) (02) (03)` or `no01 no02 no03`. http://rextester.com/OGRM21196

Comment: Here's an update using the optimized Regex. http://rextester.com/LABC16523

Comment: It is working with multiple other filters http://rextester.com/NFV68214

Comment: Use a more efficient `$@"(?<!\S)(?:{string.Join("|", matches)})(?!\S)"`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I have a new question maybe you will check out. It comebines this answer with another answer for the filter list. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49742572/6806643

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex in code:

```
     string sentence = "This is a 01 02 03 (01) (02) (03) no01 no02 no03 test";
     var newSentence = Regex.Replace(sentence, @"\s\d+(?=\s)", string.Empty);

     // Display New Sentence
     Console.WriteLine(newSentence);
```

Comment: I don't think this is perfect but it's the right approach IMO